# VPN configuration on Kali Linux with certificate PFX

Tags: linux, kali-linux, openvpn, vpn, certificates

I need to connect to my organization using VPN. For this I have PFX user certificate file, VPN Group, VPN username and password and gateway itself. Everything was simple on windows, just installed pfx and configured anyconnect with these parameters.

Now I'm on Kali linux with KDE and vpnc connection says:

"The service providing the VPN connection has stopped".

What I did so far:

- openssl pkcs12 -in vpn.pfx -nocerts -out vpn.pem -nodes
- openssl pkcs12 -in vpn.pfx -nokeys -out vpn.crt -nodes
- sudo cp vpn.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates
- sudo update-ca-certificates (result :
  Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
  1 added, 0 removed; done.
  rehash: warning: skipping vpn.pem,it does not contain exactly one
  certificate or CRL)
- configured vpnc connection : [image]

Trying to connect but: "The service providing the VPN connection has stopped".
How can I make it work? help pls.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either [Cisco's Anyconnect client for Linux](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/smb/routers/cisco-rv-series-small-business-routers/Kmgmt-785-AnyConnect-Linux-Ubuntu.html), these instructions are for Ubuntu 20.04, a Debian derivative like Kali, it should work.

Or you can use [strongSwan](https://strongswan.org/); I had success using it to connect instead of Anyconnect, actually I could handle routes as I liked (having access to the Internet using my connection), so I preferred it to Cisco client. Unfortunately I haven't got the configuration I did, it was for a company I no longer work for. If I locate anything I'll update the answer.